# accessing another model value in beforeSave() in yiii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

> A model fields and B model fields in same form

Ex:

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'a';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id','b_id'], 'id'],
    ];
}
public function beforeSave($insert) 
{
    //I want to save b model here
}
```

**I cant access B model attributes in beforeSave()**

Comment: If you  need only save the model b before model a you can do in a simple way  in controller . could you explain me why you are trying to save the model b in beforeSave .of the model A ..?

Comment: I want to use REST in my app so i need all transaction in model

Comment: The fact that you want to use REST does not imply that you should use .. BeforeSave () .. even REST uses a controller and action .. anyway .. if tiy need model B in beforeSave() of modelA you can or passthe modelB as  a parameter or add a var in modelA   with contain modelB ref